# Changing background and forecolor of buttonfield in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` where I want to change the `ButtonField` style to match up to the style of my grid. Here is my `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="936px" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Style="text-align: center">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskId" HeaderText="TaskId" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"
            SortExpression="TaskId" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Body" HeaderText="Body" SortExpression="Body" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Reward" HeaderText="Reward(Rs)" SortExpression="Reward" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TimeAllotted" HeaderText="Time(Min)" SortExpression="TimeAllotted" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PosterName" HeaderText="Uploader" SortExpression="PosterName" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Select" Text="Perform Task" />
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I've tried to use `BackColor` and `ForeColor` attributes but they aren't valid attributes for a `ButtonField`.

Comment: ControlStyle-BackColor="Blue" on button. I mean any color you want to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `ControlStyle-BackColor` like the below:

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Select" Text="Perform Task" ControlStyle-BackColor="LightBlue" />
```